# Tem como usar um char em uma operação aritmética em Java?

Tags: java, operadores

O código a seguir não funciona, mas pensei em algo nesse sentido:

```
char op = '*';
...
r = (y op x);
```

Quero alterar os caracteres de `op` para fazer diferentes operações, seria isso possível de alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na linguagem não tem. Só linguagens que permitem execução de códigos arbitrários de forma dinâmica permitem isto, e em geral de uma forma diferente.

Também não existe nenhum motivo para ter isto em uma linguagem. Se você precisa de algo assim deve criar um código que trate isto e execute as operações que deseja. Tem inúmeras formas de fazer isto, mas não é o que a pergunta pede. Do que ela faça, não tem como.

De uma maneira geral terá que criar códigos complexos para realizar o trabalho corretamente. Nenhum facilitará o trabalho de codificação, se este for o objetivo. E o código certamente será menos legível. è uma péssima ideia permitir isto diretamente.

Comment: Realmente, boa explicação! A resposta acima eu explico o motivo de tentar fazer isso, mas sua resposta foi útil, me ajudou a compreender melhor. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O ideal nessa caso seria o uso de um condicional case, ai sim você poderia usar caracteres para seu caso segue o exemplo:

```
    switch (op) {
      case '+': 
             r = primeiro + segundo;
             break;
      case '-': 
            r = primeiro - segundo;
            break;
      case '*': 
            r = primeiro * segundo;
            break;
     ....
    }
```

Comment: Não se esqueça também de definir corretamente as variáveis, por exemplo r como float para evitar problema com divisão e tratar problemas  com exceções como divisão por 0